# Additional field populated via AJAX in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby for guest checkout, I have to introduce a field which is populated via an AJAX call and then when user clicks on any option, the whole form of the guest checkout is submitted.

Does it make sense to use the existing Spring MVC form for  guest checkout or use a separate form?Should we have a seaparate action configurable via Javascript for that form and how to handle the binding for the path?

Answer (score 0):

If in the jslt the field is in the same form as the existing fields, then yes just add it to your Spring form.

The fact that this field is populated by an ajax call makes no difference for the POST.